# Is using a dictionary an efficient way to handle errors?

Tags: .net, exception, error-handling

As you all probably noticed, errors from different programs you get nowadays always have that error id number, that actually means what happend.

I was thinking maybe it's a good idea to have a `Dictionary<int,string>`, when int is the error id, and the string is a description of what occurred.

For example:

```
ErrorID: 404
Description: Page not found
```

I'm asking this because I found a downside, and not sure if it is a big deal (maybe I just don't know how it's done).
As a programmer, once you catch an exception, how exactly would you associate it with the error id? (so you could eventually provide the user with the `Description` for why his operation could not work out).

Thank you.

Comment: HTTP errors have status codes.  Most other errors do not have numbers.

Comment: @SLaks I can't really agree, because I run into them in 90% of the errors I see. when installer's operation doesn't work, a networking problem or whatever it is. But the popularity is a bit off-topic since I only want to know if it's efficient.

Comment: Error codes were the only viable solution when the http protocol was written. If you are mapping them then nothing wrong with a  dictionary, unless you are interacting with something that can only understand an error code, don't go near 'em. They are a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: All those samll number of applications you mention all have to interact with stuff that can't take an error/status object, with much more meaningful and extensive data about the error.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Ah, I understand now. Thank you very much for clearing this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to transpose the *good old'error code* pattern. This is a good practice when you are dealing with exception-less languages(C for example) or black-box/remote  process (HTTP request).

In .net, you can use exceptions which include an error message :

```
throw new Exception("File not found");
```

Or even create your own exceptions :

```
class FileNotFoundException : Exception
{
  public FileNotFoundException() : base("File not found") {}
}
```

Usage:

```
throw new FileNotFoundException();
```

So, the answer : it might be a good pattern to handle error codes for errors that don't happen often. .NET dictionaries are fast, but there is an overhead. But your question is not that far from the i18n stuff.

The real question is : do you prefer error codes or exceptions ?

Comment: I did not realize they completely replace each other as you guys mentioned, this and Tony's comment to the question was a great information to me. Thank you both.